# (Boost.Python) Segmentation fault when quitting Python 3 after importing a boost python module

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, boost, boost-python

I am currently facing a problem while testing a *Boost Python* Module.
It's a basic wrapper of a C++ class, I can use it in Python without any problems (instance, access to its attributes, etc) but when I quit the Python environment, I got a "Segmentation fault". Here's what gdb tells about the error :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7bb5760 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4151
4151    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

*I am using Boost 1.55.0, with python 3.4.*

Do you guys have any idea about this type of issue ?

***EDIT :***

Here is the backtrace from gdb :

```
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=av@entry=0x7ffff7bb5760 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4151
#1  0x00007ffff787656d in _int_free (av=0x7ffff7bb5760 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4057
#2  0x00007ffff0bfc1b5 in Poco::MemoryPool::~MemoryPool() () from /usr/local/share/EikeoTools/libs/poco/lib/libPocoFoundation.so.16
#3  0x00007ffff7833259 in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x7ffff7bb56c8 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
#4  0x00007ffff78332a5 in __GI_exit (status=<optimized out>) at exit.c:104
#5  0x00007ffff7818ecc in __libc_start_main (main=0x47dae0 <main>, argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe458, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe448) at libc-start.c:321
#6  0x0000000000576225 in _start ()
```

I can't show the code, but according to the backtrace,  there is a segfault because of a poco module.(See #2). The thing is that I don't even use this library on the current project, it is just a part of a framework I need to use in my project. So, maybe it's a link problem when compiling the project ?

***EDIT 2 :***

Here's what Valgrind gives me when I try to import my library :

```
  File "***********************/Test.py", line 4, in <module>
==12275== Invalid read of size 4
==12275==    at 0x55BF21: PyObject_Free (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x52EF09: _PyUnicodeWriter_PrepareInternal (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x52F00E: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x54FBF1: PyUnicode_DecodeUTF8Stateful (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4AB3B9: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x518544: PyEval_EvalFrameEx (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4879BE: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4C05AC: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4C4DC5: PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4CB345: _PyIncrementalNewlineDecoder_decode (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x597A4B: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4A89CE: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==  Address 0x663d020 is 8,032 bytes inside a block of size 8,225 free'd
==12275==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12275==    by 0x558CE1: _PyBytes_Resize (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x57D651: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4C4DC5: PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x5979EA: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4A89CE: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x493C8F: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x4EBD09: PyObject_Call (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x552694: _Py_DisplaySourceLine (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x475586: PyTraceBack_Print (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x448414: ??? (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
==12275==    by 0x43A859: PyErr_Display (in /usr/bin/python3.4)
```

Comment: Could you please include a [mcve]?

Comment: Valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, do you guys have any idea about that issue ?

Comment: Call stack is irrelevant. It's too late to look at it. The damage occurs at some point away from and before the crash, often very, very long before and far, far away. Which is why you should be using valgrind.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But when I used Valgrind with Python, there's a lot of information and I don't know where to look at ..

Here is what I did :

valgrind python3 myScript.py

myScript.py contains :
import mylib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got a little deeper in my code, and the issue appears to come from a PyObject that is not well used. I close this thread.
I will post a new question which will be more specific.

Thanks !